# enlarge font size for verbatimTextOutput("printout") in shiny

Tags: shiny

The problem is how to enlarge the size of the printed fonts using `verbatimTextOutput("printout")`? The UI part is like:

```
mainPanel(
   h2("Outcome"),
   verbatimTextOutput("Model"),
   verbatimTextOutput("printout")
)
```

The "printout" here is generated from server as:

```
output$printout <- renderPrint({
   result <- function1111(obs$Y,obs$X,obs$G)
   lapply(result,round,3)
})
```

where the result is a list of 5 elements.

I am thinking using `div()`, but don't know how, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with CSS. See example below

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example"),
  verbatimTextOutput("printout"),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                            #printout {
                              font-size: 20px;
                            }
                            ")))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$printout <- renderText("Sample output")

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```